# Initializing a vector<vector<int>> data(m, vector<int>(n)) inside a class matrix mat(m,n)

Tags: c++, oop, vector

I have to following code:

```
class matrix{
int m,n;
vector<vector<int>> dat(m,vector<int>n);
matrix(int m, int n){this->m=m;this->n=n;}
}
```

In order to initialize dat, we must already have m and n. I doubt that this would be happening.
The error I'm getting is

> 'm' is not a type

I cannot seem to figure out how to work around this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
class matrix
{
    int m,n;
    vector<vector<int>> dat;

public:
    matrix(int m, int n) : m (m), n(n), dat(m, vector<int>(n))
    {
    }
};
```